# i have to click twice in login button to enter the dashboard - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a login page where i have to insert user and password but if i click the login button once,it redirected me back to login page. AND THE WEIRDEST part is, if i click the login button again (after i clicked once) it goes to main page without entering any user and password. Can you help me find the problem :(, This is my code :

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<?php 

session_start();

require_once('./config/konek.php');

if (!isset($_SESSION['log'])){
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($konek, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($konek, $_POST['password']);

    // Query login
    $sql_login = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname= '$username' ";
    $res_login = mysqli_query($konek,$sql_login);
    $data_login = mysqli_fetch_array($res_login);

    // Validasi kredensial
    if($data_login){
        if($password === $data_login['upass']) {
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $data_login['id'];
            $_SESSION['uname'] = $data_login['uname'];
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $data_login['uf_name'];
            $_SESSION['created'] = $data_login['ucreated_at'];
            $_SESSION['log'] = 'login';
        // Sukses login
            echo "<script>alert('Hey, Welcome! ". $data_login['uf_name'] . "); location='./index.php'</script>";
        } else {
            // Alert ketika password salah
            $_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong password!</div>';
        }
    } else {
        // Alert ketika username salah
        $_SESSION['error'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Username not found!</div>';
    }
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login | SMS</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./assets/compiled/svg/favicon-real.svg" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64" type="image/png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/compiled/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/compiled/css/app-dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/compiled/css/auth.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="assets/static/js/initTheme.js"></script>
    <div id="auth">
        
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-12">
        <div id="auth-left">
            <div class="auth-logo">
                <img src="./assets/compiled/svg/logo.svg" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <h1><b>STOCK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM.</b></h1>
            <p class="auth-subtitle mb-5">Login using Username and Password you registered before</p>

            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
            <!-- Alert error -->
            <?php 
            
            if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
                echo $_SESSION['error'];
                unset ($_SESSION['error']);
            }
            
            ?>
                <div class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-xl" placeholder="Username" name="username">
                    <div class="form-control-icon">
                        <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-xl" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                    <div class="form-control-icon">
                        <i class="bi bi-shield-lock"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg shadow-lg mt-5">Log in</button>
            </form>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7 d-none d-lg-block">
        <div id="auth-right">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

i have already find the solution all accross the internet and not once it worked

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal`.

Comment: Because to test `if (!isset($_SESSION['log'])){` before setting it. So it only redirects the second time you submit the form. And `location='./index.php'` just sets a variable called `location`

Comment: Your code also is open to XSS injections.